# Passing List<Subclass> to method expecting List<SuperClass>

Tags: java, list, generics, compiler-errors, subclass

I have a method that is expecting a `List<SuperClass>` as argument:

```
public void myMethod(List<SuperClass> list) {}
```

I want to call that method with a `List<Subclass>` something like:

```
List<SubClass> subList = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
myMethod(subList); // Got an argument mismatch error on this line.
```

Shouldn't I be able to do this when `SubClass extends SuperClass`?

Comment: You are not passing a subclass. You are passing a *list* of a subclass. The *list* is not a subclass of the other list.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, generics don't work like that. What you could do is define your method as `MyMethod(List<? extends SuperClass> list)` (by convention it should be named `myMethod(...)` btw).

The problem with `List<SuperClass>` vs. `List<SubClass>` is that you could add new elements to such lists whereas the compiler wouldn't allow you to add something to a `List<? extends SuperClass>` - and this has a reason:

Consider the following:

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}

class C extends A {}
```

If you now have a `List<A>` you could add instances of `A`, `B` and `C`. However, if you pass a `List<B>` to a method as a `List<? extends A>` parameter, the compiler doesn't know whether it is allowed to add instances of `A` or `C` to that list (it wouldn't be allowed, but in case you'd pass a `List<A>` it would be). Thus the compiler restricts you not to do so.

Defining a parameter as `List<A>` tells the compiler that is is ok to put instances of all three classes to that list. Now if you would be allowed to pass a `List<B>` as such a parameter you could end up with a `List<B>` that contains instances of `A` and/or `C`. And this is clearly not what you want and could result in runtime bugs that should be prevented at compile time already - by using generics. That's why your approach doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks - i wasnt even sure what to google. It's "extends" btw

Comment: I would give more than one upvote for this answer if I could. This is an excellent explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch - this was a very useful explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting, you can also create the list of your superClass from a list of subClass as such:

```
myMethod(new ArrayList<SuperClass>(list));
```